# Not getting Full Path from File Upload control in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am not getting full path of uploaded file in Mozilla Firefox but I am getting it in IE. Below is the code I have used to get path.

```
string strFileName = fileUpload.postedFile.FileName;
```

I have to read that file and show it on a `gridview`.

Is there any way to get the file?